# Default value not displayed for some currency fields (and displayed for others)

Tags: fields, default-value

I have a bunch of currency fields that are displayed in a lightning page using the lightning:outputfield.

All of those currency fields have a default value of 0.

2 fields out of several dozens are showing the value of €0.00.
All have the same field definition - for example:

```
    <fields>
    <fullName>aaa__c</fullName>
    <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Association d&apos;assurance accident</label>
    <precision>8</precision>
    <required>false</required>
    <scale>2</scale>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Currency</type>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>aaa_cj__c</fullName>
    <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Association d&apos;assurance accident</label>
    <precision>8</precision>
    <required>false</required>
    <scale>2</scale>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Currency</type>
</fields>
```

**Notice** : both fields only differ by their api name

where aaa__c shows a default value of €0.00 and aaa_cj__c shows no value.

Below is the output of those fields (here set on a page layout):

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Default values in field aaa_cj__c: 0, 0.00, 1.00
- Set the fields on a lightning page and a page layout

What might be the cause of such a difference in the display of those fields?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you mean this even happens on the standard Salesforce page layout?? There's no reason for that to happen. You will need to log a Case with Salesforce support because it's a bug then.

Comment: In addition to above comment please check if you are passing any parameters yourselves in URL or via event for field which are not defaulted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AND FINALLY IT WORKS !!!**

After some days forgetting this problem and concentrating on other points I had to work on, I come to see the implied page again where all the amounts should be € 0.00 and, guess what ? Amounts are set to € 0.00.

We have a saying in French that can be translated like this : "Everything comes on time to the one who can wait". Looks like the ultimate virtue in web development is "patience".

So no issue but caching issue.

Thanks to all that replied.